# Generic method with type recognition

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class, DataPacket, which looks like this

```cs
public class DataPacket
{
    public DataPacket()
    {
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

and I have a specific datapacket, called SessionDataPacket, which inherits from this DataPacket class:

```cs
public class SessionDataPacket : DataPacket
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public SessionDataPacket(string sessionId, string userId)
    {
        this.SessionId = sessionId;
        this.UserId = userId;
    }
}
```

I would like to add a function called FromJson, which creates an object of the correct class. I came up with a generic function, like so:

```cs
 public static T FromJson<T>(string json) where T : DataPacket
 {
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
 }
```

this is a function in DataPacket and which can be used to specify the type of DataPacket I would like to create. However, this will have to be called thusly:

```cs
SessionDataPacket sessionData = DataPacket.FromJson<SessionDataPacket>(responseData);
```

My question is: is there a way to call this function, without having to speficy its type in a generic method, so that I can use it like so:

```cs
SessionDataPacket sessionData = SessionDataPacket.FromJson(responseData);
```

Comment: This is called polymorphic serialization. It's supported in various ways by both JSON.NET and System.Text.Json. The JSON message itself must contain a type identifier.

Comment: But you are still specifying `SessionDataPacket`! What are you saving, `DataPacket.` and two angle brackets?

Comment: @AntonTykhyy
Essentially, yes. It's for a student project. I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: C# is not the most super concise language. Think of these dozen extra characters as syntax taxes. Any workaround, such as with generics, is sure to be more contrived and verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best not to try to do this at all. There are ways to support this but by trying to support this you are creating a new, non-standard approach that is highly specific to your runtime.

Given that you are replacing 1 line of code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionDataPacket>(json);
```

To write that in non-generic form still requires you to know the type, so there is no real gain:

```
SessionDataPacket.FromJson(json);
```

Nothing is stopping you from implementing `FromJson(string)` in your concrete types, but most inheritance implementations will result in casting the result to it's base form or implementing an interface. This is a classic case of over-encapsulation that over time you will want to avoid.

What are you really gaining by wrapping a standard library call that every .Net developer off the street will understand with your own custom proprietary implementation? It seems counter-intuitive but this is the start of negative work and thus technical debt.

There are many arguments around this, but ultimately serialization belongs outside of a class definition unless you have really specific custom serialization needs, even then you should first use the serialization attributes of the serialization library you want to use to describe your models better.

Once you start encouraging yourself and your developers to use your custom implementations, you will find that your implementation is likely to evolve or not keep up with the standards to a point where in the future it is hard to maintain your code or your developers will struggle to operate in other teams and projects where this custom *convention* is not in-place.

Just think about the effort involved here, in cases where there is a standard approach and your approach hides implied complexity through the use of more lines of code then we aren't making things any better. Reserve implementations like `FromJson` to scenarios where the class does not conform to standards or you are unable to express your deserialization logic using the standard extensibility hooks in JSON.Net or System.Text.Json

---

In scenarios where this concept becomes problematic, or when you start looking for a polymorphic deserialization handler, then it is often worth considering *composition* instead of *inheritance*. Without more detail it is hard to go into depth here, but imaging you have 3 classes that all differ only in minor details, perhaps each has one property that the others do not have...

You can compose a new type that has all three of those properties (including any or all of the common properties).

When we de-serialize into the new type, we can ignore the missing members, this will give you a type safe way to manage each of the models that you want to deserialize.

To take this closer to the *composition model*, you create an `interface` for each of the specific types you want to implement, make your composed model implement each of those interfaces, now you can implicitly cast the model through the interfaces.

This can still be over-engineering, but this is often a more flexible approach for DTOs and functional programming where most of the business logic is outside of the concrete types.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a matter of opinion on which option is "cleaner" or more preferred, but one option is to specify the type in the inheritance rather than in the method.  For example, consider this base class:

```
public class DataPacket<T> where T : DataPacket<T>
{
    public DataPacket()
    {
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public static T FromJson(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

The method no longer needs the type specifier, as it gets that from the class itself.  Inheriting classes would need to specify themselves in their declaration:

```
public class SessionDataPacket : DataPacket<SessionDataPacket>
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public SessionDataPacket(string sessionId, string userId)
    {
        this.SessionId = sessionId;
        this.UserId = userId;
    }
}
```

Which may be a little unsightly, but it's only once in the class definition itself.  Throughout the codebase you don't need the type specifiers:

```
var sessionData = SessionDataPacket.FromJson(responseData);
```

Comment: Sometimes I need the base class without any type specifications; for example, I have a Queue<DataPacket> that will store data packets when the connection is lost, and then dequeue and send all the data packets once the connection is re-established. Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I think this approach doesn't allow for such data structures?

Perhaps Anton is right that it isn't a big problem and I am just over-engineering it.
Thanks for your reponse regardless! :)

Comment: @GeekPeek I think you are overengineering this for sure. This only satisfies the syntax you requested but it sounds like you want a polymorphic response, that is a single method that returns the specific type to match the content. That is different again.

Comment: This is called the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. It's annoying that C# doesn't have a `where T : this` constraint, which would prevent `public class EvilSessionDataPacket : DataPacket<SessionDataPacket>`